# Swift 3 Image Slider with button can't change imageview

Tags: swift, xcode, image, button, swift3

There is image slider. I have made a image slider and each is button. I also change the image of button, and now I can't click the button in image slider to change the UIImageView "imgtoy". I want to click the button, then UIImageView will change to each photo in my choosetoy array. Anyone can help me? Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgtoy: UIImageView!


var itemImage: Int = 2
var imageName: String = ""
var imgBackground = [UIImage(named: "btnballicon.png"), UIImage(named: "btneastfin.png"), UIImage(named: "btnmarblefin.png"), UIImage(named: "btnplanefin.png"), UIImage(named: "btntoyfin.png")]

private let choosetoy = ["ballfin.png", "eastfin.png", "marblefin.png", "planefin.png", "toyfin.png"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    imageName = choosetoy[itemImage]
    self.imgtoy.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imgBackground.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "foodCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! foodCollectionViewCell


    cell.imgfood.setImage(imgBackground[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)


    itemImage = indexPath.row

    return cell
}

@IBAction func choosetoy(_ sender: Any) {
    if itemImage != nil {
        imageName = choosetoy[itemImage]
        self.imgtoy.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

    }
}
```

Comment: have u reloadData in button action

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad what's reloadData. I am beginner of swift3

Comment: if you want to change your collection or table data then you have to reload the data in button method.like   'CollectionViewObj.reloadData()'.

Comment: @HappyChan `reloadData` is not part of Swift, it's part of UITableView.

Comment: But it can work on collectionView too..https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618078-reloaddata

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad Of course. :) I was just answering to OP's comment `what's reloadData. I am beginner of swift3` It looked like they thought `reloadData` was in Swift, so I gave a hint about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update code as below,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "foodCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! foodCollectionViewCell


    cell.imgfood.setImage(imgBackground[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)


    cell.imgfood.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}

@IBAction func choosetoy(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imageName = choosetoy[sender.tag]
        self.imgtoy.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
}
```

Comment: It's work. So I want to know what's .tag? Why tag can get the number which I click the image?